# How can I extract one value from this JSON ARRAY?

Tags: python, json, data-extraction

This is the data I get from MPI ELAN, it's a about movie file used in that program:

```
'[{"MEDIA_URL": "file:///Volumes/MINI RUGGED/MULTIMET2015/JOINT/29-60-S1.avi", "MIME_TYPE": "video/*", "TIME_ORIGIN": "176040"}, {"MEDIA_URL": "file:///Volumes/MINI RUGGED/MULTIMET2015/JOINT/29-60-S1-LEWA.mp4", "MIME_TYPE": "video/mp4", "TIME_ORIGIN": "100408"}, {"MEDIA_URL": "file:///Volumes/MINI RUGGED/MULTIMET2015/JOINT/29-60-S1-PRAWA.mp4", "MIME_TYPE": "video/mp4", "TIME_ORIGIN": "82199"}, {"MEDIA_URL": "file:///Volumes/MINI RUGGED/MULTIMET2015/JOINT/29-60-S1.mp3", "MIME_TYPE": "audio/*"}]'
```

I'd like to extract the value from this key: "TIME_ORIGIN": "82199" and I think this is JSON ARRAY, but I can't do it.

Comment: There are multiple dictionaries within the list. Are you trying to extract all of the `TIME_ORIGIN` values?

Comment: Try out the `json` library (`import json`) for parsing in the string to a `list` of `dict`, then you'll be able to work with it.

Comment: I've tried json_array = json.load(dane)
where dane stands for the json string
and I got an error in python PyCharm:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Try `json.loads()`, rather than `json.load()`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list

Comment: OK, this the way I need it:
https://www.example-code.com/python/json_array_load_and_parse.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use json.loads(load json from string):

Here is a working example:

```
import json

my_json_string = '[{"MEDIA_URL": "file:///Volumes/MINI RUGGED/MULTIMET2015/JOINT/29-60-S1.avi", "MIME_TYPE": "video/*", "TIME_ORIGIN": "176040"}, {"MEDIA_URL": "file:///Volumes/MINI RUGGED/MULTIMET2015/JOINT/29-60-S1-LEWA.mp4", "MIME_TYPE": "video/mp4", "TIME_ORIGIN": "100408"}, {"MEDIA_URL": "file:///Volumes/MINI RUGGED/MULTIMET2015/JOINT/29-60-S1-PRAWA.mp4", "MIME_TYPE": "video/mp4", "TIME_ORIGIN": "82199"}, {"MEDIA_URL": "file:///Volumes/MINI RUGGED/MULTIMET2015/JOINT/29-60-S1.mp3", "MIME_TYPE": "audio/*"}]'

my_json = json.loads(my_json_string)

print(my_json[0]['TIME_ORIGIN'])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def podajczasyfilmów(plikeaf)
  annofile = pympi.Elan.Eaf(plikeaf)
  dane = annofile.get_linked_files()
  dane = json.dumps(dane)
  jsonArray = chilkat.CkJsonArray()
  jsonArray.Load(dane)
  i = 0
  ltime = []
  lfile = []
  while i < jsonArray.get_Size() :
      jsonObj = jsonArray.ObjectAt(i)
      lplik = jsonObj.stringOf("MEDIA_URL")
      lczas = jsonObj.stringOf("TIME_ORIGIN")
      ltime.append(lczas)
      lfile.append(lplik)
      i = i + 1
  dfall = pd.DataFrame(ltime,lfile)
```